# How to dynamically show columns in a Jasper Report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, conditional-statements

I am generating a Jasper Report, which has  5 fixed columns. The client has requested the ability to select the number of columns at run time.

For example if he checks 2 columns from a displayed JTable then there should be 2 columns in Jasper report, if he checks 4 then there should be four columns in jasper report. To try to solve this I am thinking of adding condition in jasper report. If the client selects column A and B I will set that as a parameter in the report and use that to determine whether to display the column.

In order to do these, I need to use conditions in the Jasper XML. Where should I set the conditions in the report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following

1. Create a `HashMap` and set the required properties in it

   > ```
   > Map params = new HashMap();
   > params.put("DISPLAY_COLUMN_ONE", "Y")
   > ```
2. Pass this `params` map to Jasper in the method

   `JasperFillManager.fillReport`
3. In your JRXML, create a parameter corresponding to each property set
   in the hashmap above:

   `<parameter name="DISPLAY_COLUMN_ONE" class="java.lang.String"/>`
4. Display the columns based on the parameter value

   `<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{DISPLAY_COLUMN_ONE}.equals("Y")]]></printWhenExpression>`

Comment: can you please prove the syntax for example

Comment: <textField>
    <reportElement x="690" y="2" width="100" height="20"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
     <font isBold="false"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customer_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>

Answer (score 2):

you should pass **columnCount** parameter to jasper and check condition in each column's  **Print when Expression**.

first column **Print when Expression** is

```
$P{columnCount} >=1
```

Second column **Print when Expression** is

```
$P{columnCount} >=2
```

Third column **Print when Expression** is

```
$P{columnCount} >=3
```

Fourth column **Print when Expression** is

```
$P{columnCount} >=4
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: please prove the syntax for print when expression

Comment: <textField>
    <reportElement x="690" y="2" width="100" height="20"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
     <font isBold="false"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customer_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>

Answer (score 0):

I would just make multiple copies of your jasper report, one for each variation of number of columns. It may be a lot of redundancy, but it's very easy as long as the number of possible variations isn't too high. The report you end up calling depends on the user's selection.

I can't think of any way of varying the columns within a report based on a conditional.